# Flutter android app crashes when trying to open a Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to implement firebase dynamic linking in my Flutter android app. When I try to open a deeplink url, the app crashes without giving any log error.

The following is my **intent-filter** in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="testdynamiclinking.page.link" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I have set `compileSdkVersion` to 33 and `minSdkVersion` to 21.

I would like to know if I'm making any mistake and how to fix the issue.